# Half-transparent elements in the Adobe Illustrator have a black outlines

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new in Adobe Illustrator and I just need to extract one element from EPS-file.

So it's the light. And as you see in the attached file, I can't save it clean.
I mean, when it has a some background, it looks good.
But when I remove this background and trying to save the clean light as PNG image this is what happenes.

[Here's the demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fldQB.png)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me as if you need to select that image in illustrator then open your align pallet and select the option "align to artboard" then click the vertical align button then the horizontal align button. Then go ahead and try saving your file. It should take care of the problem.